# Emacs can't find Node when Node was installed using NVM

Tags: eshell, bash, environment

I've got Node installed using [NVM](http://github.com/creationix/nvm), and Emacs (v25.2.1) isn't able to find Node. When I run `M-: (executable-find "node")` I get back `nil`.

However, when I run `M-: (executable-find "cat")` I get `"/bin/cat"`. I assume the difference is due to my use of NVM.

**How do I get Emacs to find Node when I've got Node installed using NVM?**

## Incidental technical details:

My Emacs was installed using MacPorts (using the `emacs-app` package that installs to the Mac Applications folder for a GUI experience), and I've got the following lines in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR="/Users/fred/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

My `~/.bash_profile` contains `source ~/.bashrc`.

I'm not sure if this is relevant to the problem, but I should mention that when I open `M-x eshell`, I get the following when trying to run Node:

```
$ node
node: command not found
```

However, I am able to run Node through `M-x shell`.

I did have limited success installing the `emacs` package (as opposed to the `emacs-app` package) from MacPorts. Using the Emacs from the `emacs` package (which installs to /opt/local/bin/emacs), I was able to evaluate in the *scratch* buffer:

```
(executable-find "node")
```

And successfully got the path to node. However, this same lisp expression evaluated in the Emacs from the `emacs-app` package yielded `nil`. This doesn't help me much, because I want to use the emacs from `emacs-app`, because it's the Emacs with the graphical interface for Mac, as I understand it.

I want to continue using NVM, please.

Comment: The doc-string for `executable-find` states:  "*Search for COMMAND in ‘exec-path’ and return the absolute file name.  Return nil if COMMAND is not found anywhere in ‘exec-path’.*"  You can inspect the `exec-path` with `C-h v` or `M-x describe-variable`.  If the path containing the `node` executable is not there, then you will be one step closer to troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Most likely, your .bashrc code has no effect because there's no bash involved (i.e. you start Emacs from the GUI which has not executed a bash shell).

Comment: I run my emacs in the terminal. And my emacs shell sees the system node, rather than the nvm node. Seems very silly. I guess nvm is doing something sneaky. rvm works fine. The nvm default is set to the node version I want. But nvm just doesn't play nice.

Answer (score 13):

## Best solution:

Install `exec-path-from-shell`. From the [documentation](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell), after calling `(package-initialize)`, add the following to your .emacs file:

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

## Another solution:

Add the following to your .emacs file:

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.0/bin")))
```

Your version number in the string above may differ. I don't like this solution as much as the "best solution," because it must be manually updated to keep the emacs path synchronized with the system path.

Comment: After appending a new path to `exec-path` to point to an `nvm` path it still shows me `"/usr/bin/node"` when evaluating `(executable-find "node")`. Maybe I should consider deleting `node` from `/usr/bin/node`?

Comment: @EvgenyMikhaylov You could try `(push "/path/to/node/bin" exec-path)` instead of `append` to make the new path you're adding take precedence over `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @g-gundam thank you! But I have already deleted files `node` and `nodejs` from `/usr/bin/`. I have no idea though whether it could leave some remnants.

Comment: @EvgenyMikhaylov I'd be careful with that.  If your package management system installed node there, it might become confused when it can't find it later.