# Emacs can't find Node when Node was installed using NVM (again)

Tags: eshell, javascript, path

My question is similar to [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34201/emacs-cant-find-node-when-node-was-installed-using-nvm) question. I've installed node via nvm.   `(executable-find "node")` returns `.nvm/versions/node/v15.11.0/bin/node`.

Entering `node` on eshell drops me into a node shell. But when I enter `npm` in an eshell, I'm fed

`/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

Similarly, the command `nvm` returns `nvm: command not found`.

On a zsh terminal, the above commands work as expected. I suspect this has to do with the following line in my `.zshrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

I can use `(setenv "NVM_DIR" "~/.nvm")` to set the env var, I'm at a loss per the second line.

including the line   `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.11.0/bin")))` does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that nvm is actually a set of bash functions and doesn't work outside of bash.  The following blog post has a detailed account of the issue and a work around using `nvm-exec` solution:
https://jloubert.com/blog/eshell-nvm/

The author purposes adding an `.nvmrc` file to your projects that has the required nvm version number in it.

They then purpose adding an eshell alias that calls `npm-exec` and you prefix any node commands with that alias. The eshell alias code looks like where `"foo"` is the alias keyword

```
(defvar my/nvm-folder "/my/path/to/.nvm")
(add-hook
 'eshell-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (eshell/alias
    "foo"
    (concat my/nvm-folder
            "/nvm-exec foo-server run"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't necessarily clarify what you're using node/npm for, this is if you're a Python, etc. dev who might need npm/node in emacs for LSPs (as was my use case when I found this answer, and nvm was easiest AUR installation). If that is the case, you could theoretically just do something as simple as creating a script such as:

https://gist.github.com/MeLlamoPablo/0abcc150c10911047fd9e5041b105c34

```sh
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/node
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/npm
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/bin/
sudo ln -s $(which npm) /usr/bin/
```

symlinking your default node/npm, allowing emacs to pick it up and rerunning the script on the off chance you switch defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) package? It loads the environment variables that are used in your shell.

If you are using `use-package` then this should suffice:

```
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
   :config (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

Comment: exec-path-from-shell only copies over environmental path values and does not handle the shell script execution of the 2nd line that op pointed out.